# FabricJS - How to prevent leaving object from the given object?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I was able to prevent leaving objects from the canvas but I was not able to prevent leaving child objects from the given object.

I tried to do it in this way (see code example below) but this locks the object leaving in the same size (width, height) of the locked object but positioned absolutely (top, left). I need to prevent leaving in the same coords there the parent object is positioned (see please the attached image).

Any ideas are welcome.

[image]

```
preventLeavingInsideBox(e: IEvent) {
    let activeObject = e.target;
    if ((activeObject.get('left') - (activeObject.get('width') * activeObject.get('scaleX')  / 2) < 0))
      activeObject.set('left', activeObject.get('width') * activeObject.get('scaleX')  / 2);
    if ((activeObject.get('top') - (activeObject.get('height') * activeObject.get('scaleY')  / 2) < 0))
      activeObject.set('top', activeObject.get('height') * activeObject.get('scaleY')  / 2);
    if (activeObject.get('left') + (activeObject.get('width') * activeObject.get('scaleX')  / 2) > this.rect.width)
    {
      var positionX = this.rect.width - (activeObject.get('width') * activeObject.get('scaleX'))  / 2;
      activeObject.set('left', positionX > this.rect.width / 2 ? positionX : this.rect.width / 2);
    }
    if (activeObject.get('top') + (activeObject.get('height') * activeObject.get('scaleY') / 2) > this.rect.height)
    {
      var positionY = this.rect.height - (activeObject.get('height') * activeObject.get('scaleY') / 2);
      activeObject.set('top', positionY > this.rect.height / 2 ? positionY : this.rect.height / 2);
    }

    //below just prevention for object from getting width or height greater than canvas width and height
    if (activeObject.get('width')  * activeObject.get('scaleX') > this.rect.width)
    {
      activeObject.set('scaleX', this.rect.width / activeObject.get('width'));
    }
    if (activeObject.get('height') * activeObject.get('scaleY') > this.rect.height)
    {
      activeObject.set('scaleY', this.rect.height / activeObject.get('height'));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve the same result. I had an object with an image inside that I didn't want to be able to be moved outside of it and I also did the resize too.

So I had to get the object that frame which held the image originally and then adds the image after.

What you need to take into account is the top & left of the holding object and the movable object.

So I have a ID on my object of feature image so I get access to it from that. and get the original top, left, height & width.

```
const featureImageBoxDetails = {
    top: featureImageBox.top,
    left: featureImageBox.left,
    right: featureImageBox.left + featureImageBox.width * featureImageBox.scaleX,
    bottom: featureImageBox.top + featureImageBox.height * featureImageBox.scaleY,
    width: featureImageBox.width * featureImageBox.scaleX,
    height: featureImageBox.height * featureImageBox.scaleY,
};
```

Then I have my `preventLeavingInsideBox` function:

```
const preventLeavingInsideBox = (e: IEvent) => {
    const activeObject = e.target;
    const activeObjectDetails = {
        top: activeObject.top,
        left: activeObject.left,
        right: activeObject.left + activeObject.width * activeObject.scaleX,
        bottom: activeObject.top + activeObject.height * activeObject.scaleY,
        width: activeObject.width * activeObject.scaleX,
        height: activeObject.height * activeObject.scaleY,
    };
    // right
    if (activeObjectDetails.right <= featureImageBoxDetails.right) {
        activeObject.set({
            left: featureImageBoxDetails.right - activeObjectDetails.width,
        });
    }
    // left
    if (activeObjectDetails.left >= featureImageBoxDetails.left) {
        activeObject.set({
            left: featureImageBoxDetails.left,
        });
    }
    // bottom
    if (activeObjectDetails.bottom <= featureImageBoxDetails.bottom) {
        activeObject.set({
            top: featureImageBoxDetails.top + featureImageBoxDetails.height - activeObjectDetails.height,
        });
    }
    // Top
    if (activeObjectDetails.top >= featureImageBoxDetails.top) {
        activeObject.set({
            top: featureImageBoxDetails.top,
        });
    }
};
```

Then you just need to add in the:

```
canvas.on('object:moving', preventLeavingInsideBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same need but need more

i just need this same feature. and its working fine but when we do the same with rotated object its works strange. can you please

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33482530)